# Xcode unit test: Permission denied when trying to write test data from unit test to project folder

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, cocoa, sandbox, xctest

I have an Xcode unit test for a Cocoa app running on macOS. When the unit test runs, I'd like to save some data to the app's project folder so that I can read it back the next time the test runs (I'm trying to use this [snapshot testing library](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing)).

However, trying to create the output directory fails with a permission denied error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “TestOutput”
in the folder “__Snapshots__”." 
UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/test/code/TestApp/TestOutput/__Snapshots__/SimpleTest,
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c0c0c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

I assume that's because the unit test runs sandboxed and is not allowed to access files and directories outside of the temporary directory.

Is there any way to extend the unit test's sandbox to include access to a specific directory in the app's project folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just store your file in the *application support* folder. This folder is within the sandbox and its purpose is to store data required by the app.

You can get its path using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` and should check it exists (at the returned path), creating it if needed.

**Addendum after comment:**

There is a deprecated entitlement which may work for you, [`com.apple.security.files.all`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_files_all), but don't try to use it in anything you distribute via Apple! Using this might effect your tests as they can access everything as well... Historically there were entitlements that granted access to specific paths, a bit of archeology on the web might turn those up as well.

The proper way to do this is to store a [*security scoped bookmark*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) but you do need some user-interaction to get it going: on first run throw up a standard file open dialog for the user to select the folder to store the files in and then construct and save (e.g. in user defaults) a society scoped bookmark. On subsequent runs just load the bookmark and activate it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem is that the files are part of the project source and under version control. My current workaround is to copy them to $TMPDIR before I run the tests and back into the source folder afterwards. I'm hoping there's a way to extend the sandbox so that this step is not necessary.

Comment: @Mark - added an addendum. HTH